# Amazon OpsWorks NodeJs New Relic Integration

Tags: node.js, newrelic, aws-opsworks

I am trying to get application metrics from my nodejs app on AWS OpsWorks.  I have been able to get server monitoring working. However, application metrics are not working. When I look at the log, it says ***No metrics to send*** as if it hasn't collected anything and the Application overview screen in New Relic says the application is idle.

- I have followed all the setup instructions
- I require newrelic at the top of my server
- I am using a simple post route in the Restify framework

Has anyone had any success integrating nodejs-agent with an Amazon OpsWorks NodeJs layer app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a loop in terminal to curl my endpoint every 1 second for 86400 iterations.  New Relic started showing results, though the counts were reported as only 1 - 3 per minute when it should have been closer to 60.  It seems my problem was that my endpoint was very simple and the server spent around 0 - 1 ms and so the nodejs agent didn't realize it had metrics.  When I did an actual load test where the requests started taking around 200ms, I began to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting this issue would require working with New Relic support to determine what's going on here.
There's a discussion about this on the New Relic community forums which would be a better place to work on this.
Once we have a definitive answer to this situation we can post a reply here for others to benefit from.

The current discussion is going on here: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/amazon-opsworks-integration/4306